# how to disable the SwipeRefreshLayout in Landscape mode

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, swiperefreshlayout

I want to disable the `SwipeRefreshLayout` in the `landscape` mode when screen rotates the `SwipeRefreshLayout` must disable automatically.

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        refresh.setEnabled(false);
        refresh.setRefreshing(false);

    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
        getSupportActionBar().show();
        getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        refresh.setEnabled(true);
    }
}

refresh.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {
        videoData("video");
        refresh.setRefreshing(true);
        (new Handler()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                refresh.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        }, 5000);
    }
});

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/listCoordinate"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#b2100f0f">

        <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            android:id="@+id/refresh"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center">

            <utils.VideoRecyclerview
                android:id="@+id/videoRecyclerview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:footerDividersEnabled="false"
                android:gravity="center_vertical" />

        </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    </FrameLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: why you are using this line refresh.setRefreshing(true); in your code

Comment: for refreshing the list...

Comment: please remove that and try, it automatically  do that thing it is not needed

Comment: @Awadesh  
now in landscape list is not refreshing as in want but circle is still visible

Comment: when circle is visible ? i did'nt get you, after refreshing you have to set the data in your layout again, then it will go automatically

Comment: @Awadesh when i pull the list down in recyclerview in landscape mode the list does not refresh as i disable refreshing using      refresh.setEnabled(false);
                            refresh.setRefreshing(false); but the loading circle is visible when in pull down the list..

Comment: can you post your xml file, you have to debug the code when you are swiping down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well that's a thing that came to my main I'm not saying that will be the best way to do it, but it might work...

In your `SwipeRefreshLayout` where you do the stuff you could ask if the device is in `Landscape` and you can do it this way :

```
if(getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE){
//Landscape mode
}
```

even with

```
if(getRequestedOrientation() == ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
```

So I guess you can return false if the orientation is landscape.

### EDIT

Well then try this way :

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
  super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
  if(newConfig == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE){
     yourSwipeLayoutRefresh.setEnabled(false);
     yourSwipeLayoutRefresh.setRefreshing(false);
  }
}
```

*Note: if your `SwipeLayoutRefresh` is not in the same class, you could make it static then you can access it but always asking if it's not null*

Comment: I know i have to implement it in the onConfigurationChanged method.. but what should call to disable it..

Comment: can we hide the SwipeLayoutRefresh loading circle

Comment: @user6071487 see my answer (two line code at bottom) if you want to hide the loading circle,

Comment: Did you add `yourSwipeLayoutRefresh.setRefreshing(false);` ?

Answer (score 0):

In order to disable the 'SwiperefreshLayout', you have to disable it in the Landscape mode :

To disable

```
swipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(false);
```

To enable:

```
swipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(true);
```

Now to find the Orientation of the device you can use this condition:

```
if(getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE){
    //Do some stuff
}
```

And you may need to detect the event when orientationn changes, for that you can override this method:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    //Do stuff here
}
```

if it is already refreshing then it keeps refreshing when you change the orientation so you have to check like this: put this code in your overridden method.

```
if (swipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing()) {
    swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
}
```

Comment: not working..it still refreshing the list in landscape mode

Comment: is this working ,please do le me know.if you want to hide the SwipeLayoutRefresh loading circle use this .. if (swipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing()) {
                    swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                }

Comment: it's not hiding the circle

Comment: your method code is fine, one thing if you have refreshed and then disabled, it keeps refreshing so wherever you are using your swiperefreshLayout, put setrefreshing(false) there also

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    int orientation = newConfig.orientation;
     if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
        refreshLayout.setEnabled(false)


   }
```